# Bootstrap collapse with rails each loop

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstraps collapse feature to work with a loop in rails. Currently only the first item in the loop works, but when the second item is clicked it just collapses the first item. Below is my code. What's the best way to make this dynamic?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        <h3><%= i.firstname %><%= i.lastname %></h3>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
    <%= i.email %></br>
        Payed: <%= i.payed? %></br>
        Birthday: <%= i.dateofbirth %><br />
        Address: <%= i.address %><br />
        City: <%= i.city %><br />
        Province: <%= i.province %><br />
        Phone Number: <%= i.phonenumber %><br />
        Service Provider: <%= i.serviceprovider %><br />
        Gender: <%= i.gender %><br />
        Languages: <%= i.languages %><br />

        <h3>School Information</h3>
        Highschool: <%= i.app.highschool %><br />
        Address: <%= i.app.highschool_address %><br />
        City: <%= i.app.highschool_city %><br />
        Province: <%= i.app.highschool_province %><br />
        Postal Code: <%= i.app.highschool_postalcode %><br />

        <h4>Post Secondary Schools of Interest</h4>
        <% i.app.postsecondaries.each do |ps| %>
        Post Secondary Name: <%= ps.postsecondary %><br />
        Address: <%= ps.postsecondary_address %><br />
        City: <%= ps.postsecondary_city %><br />
        Province: <%= ps.postsecondary_province %><br />
        Postal Code: <%= ps.postsecondary_postalcode %><br />
        Country: <%= ps.postsecondary_country %><br />
        Program: <%= ps.postsecondary_program %><br />
        Faculty: <%= ps.postsecondary_faculty %><br />
        Status: <%= ps.postsecondary_status %><br />
        <% end %>
        </div>


        <div class="span3 well">
        <h3>Grades</h3>
        <% i.app.grades.each do |grade| %>
        <br />Course: <%= grade.course %><br />
        Grade: <%= grade.course_grade %>
        <% end %>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 well">

        <h3>Extracurricular Activities</h3>
        <% i.app.extra_activities.each do |e| %>
        Activity: <%= e.activity %><br />
        Position: <%= e.activity_position %><br />
        Dates: <%= e.activity_dates %><br />
        Times Per Week: <%= e.activity_timeperweek %><br />
        Contact Name: <%= e.activity_contact %><br />
        Contact Position: <%= e.activity_contact_position %><br />
        Contact Phone Number: <%= e.activity_contact_phonenumber %><br />
        Contact Email: <%= e.activity_contact_email %><br />
        Description: <%= e.activity_description %>
        <% end %>

        <h3>Essay 1</h3>
        Describe the situation: <%= i.app.describe_situation %></br>
        </br>Explain the actions you took in response to the situation: <%= i.app.explain_action %></br>
        </br>Identify the good that resulted once the situation was resolved: <%= i.app.resolved_situation %></br>
        </br>What personal strength or skill did you use that was key in determining the outcome?: <%= i.app.personal_skill %></br>

        <h3>Essay 2</h3>
        Describe the situation: <%= i.app.describe_situation_two %></br>
        </br>Explain the actions you took in response to the situation: <%= i.app.explain_action_two %></br>
        </br>Identify the good that resulted once the situation was resolved: <%= i.app.resolved_situation_two %></br>
        </br>What personal strength or skill did you use that was key in determining the outcome?: <%= i.app.personal_skill_two %></br>

        <h3>Essay 3</h3>
        Describe the situation: <%= i.app.describe_situation_three %></br>
        </br>Explain the actions you took in response to the situation: <%= i.app.explain_action_three %></br>
        </br>Identify the good that resulted once the situation was resolved: <%= i.app.resolved_situation_three %></br>
        </br>What personal strength or skill did you use that was key in determining the outcome?: <%= i.app.personal_skill_three %></br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's happening is that the id of the accordion element is not changing in the loop.  So you have multiple elements that have the same id.  This causes the clicking of any of them to default to the first one (javascript chooses the first id it can find). You probably want to use ruby's `each_with_index` ([docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index)) function to add the correct classes to the accordion

that is

```
<% collection_of_users.each_with_index do |i, index| %>
  ...
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse<%= index.to_s %>">
  ...
  <div id="collapse<&= index.to_s %>" class="accordion-body collapse in">
<% end %>
```

note that you also have to make sure to change the link that points to each collapse portion in the body.  Also, I'm not 100% sure that the `to_s` is necessary in the embedded ruby, but better to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

I think this may be more accurate solution to your ploberm.

```
      <ul>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <% collection_of_users.each_with_index do |i, index| %>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<%= index+1 %>">
                  <%= i_title.capitalize %>
                </a></li>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse<%= index+1 %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                ............................
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4:

```
<% [1, 2, 3].each do |a| %>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordion<%= a %>">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="heading<%= a %>">
        <h2 class="mb-0">
          <button aria-controls="collapse<%= a %>" aria-expanded="true" class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" data-target="#collapse<%= a %>" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<%= a %>" id="collapse<%= a %>">
        <div class="card-body">
          <%= a %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```